# ¿ Cómo hacer que al clickar un dia en mi calendarView se muestre lo que yo quiera?

Tags: java, android

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.CalendarView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.herprogramacion.restaurantericoparico.R;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private DrawerLayout drawerLayout;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.actividad_principal);


        ///// ESTO ES LO QUE TENGO PUESTO PERO ME SALE ERROR Y NO ME EJECUTA APLICACION

        CalendarView calendarView=(CalendarView) findViewById(R.id.calendarView);
        calendarView.setOnDateChangeListener(new CalendarView.OnDateChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onSelectedDayChange(CalendarView view, int year, int month,
                                            int dayOfMonth) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ""+dayOfMonth, 0).show();// TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });
        ///// ESTO ES LO QUE TENGO PUESTO PERO ME SALE ERROR Y NO ME EJECUTA APLICACION
        agregarToolbar();

        drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);

        if (navigationView != null) {
            prepararDrawer(navigationView);
            // Seleccionar item por defecto
            seleccionarItem(navigationView.getMenu().getItem(0));
        }
    }

    private void agregarToolbar() {
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        final ActionBar ab = getSupportActionBar();
        if (ab != null) {
            // Poner ícono del drawer toggle
            ab.setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.drawer_toggle);
            ab.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        }
    }

    private void prepararDrawer(NavigationView navigationView) {
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(
            new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) {
                    menuItem.setChecked(true);
                    seleccionarItem(menuItem);
                    drawerLayout.closeDrawers();
                    return true;
                }
            });
    }

    private void seleccionarItem(MenuItem itemDrawer) {
        Fragment fragmentoGenerico = null;
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();

        switch (itemDrawer.getItemId()) {

            case R.id.CALENDARIO:

                fragmentoGenerico = new FragmentoPerfil();

                break;

            case R.id.PRIMERO:
                fragmentoGenerico = new FragmentPrimero();
                break;

            case R.id.SEGUNDO:
                fragmentoGenerico = new FragmentSegundo();
                break;

            case R.id.TERCERO:
                fragmentoGenerico = new FragmentTercero();
                break;

            case R.id.CUARTO:
                fragmentoGenerico = new FragmentCuarto();
                break;

            case R.id.nav_share:
                Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                sharingIntent.setType("text/plain");
                sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "AndroidSolved");
                sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "si que funciona");
                startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, "Share via"));
                break;


        }

        if (fragmentoGenerico != null) {
            fragmentManager
                    .beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.contenedor_principal, fragmentoGenerico)
                    .commit();
        }

        // Setear título actual
        setTitle(itemDrawer.getTitle());
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_actividad_principal, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case android.R.id.home:
                drawerLayout.openDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
                return true;

            case R.id.Internet:

                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_BROWSABLE);
                intent.setData(Uri.parse("https://www.intranet.upv.es"));
                startActivity(intent);
                break;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Mi aplicacion es un drawer y en una de esas opciones esta el calendario, que está más arriba en el 1º case. Lo que quiero es por ejemplo que al clickar en el 15 de septiembre me salga un toast diciendo "hoy es 15" o un texto que yo quiera.

Comment: Hola acabo de ver tu pregunta en tu layout actividad_principal.xml debes tener calendarView, revisa mi respuesta.

Answer (score 2):

Simplemente asegura que en tu layout `actividad_principal.xml` se encuentre tu elemento `calendarView` al cual haces referencia:

```
  public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.actividad_principal);

        CalendarView calendarView = (CalendarView) findViewById(R.id.calendarView);        

        calendarView.setOnDateChangeListener(new OnDateChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onSelectedDayChange(CalendarView view, int year, int month,
                    int dayOfMonth) {
                  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ""+dayOfMonth, 0).show();

            }
        });
    }
```

Si no contienes tu elemento `calendarView` en el layout, no se podrá ejecutar el listener.

Comment: Elena, el problema que donde tengo el calendarView ( y debe estar ahí...) es un Fragment no "extends AppCompatActivity"

Answer (score 0):

Prueba con esto, a mi me funciona bien:

```
calendarView.setOnDateChangeListener(new OnDateChangeListener() {       
    @Override
    public void onSelectedDayChange(CalendarView view, int year, int month, int dayOfMonth) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ""+dayOfMonth, 0).show();
    }
});
```

Comment: Si leyeras lo que pongo... es lo que tengo y nada...